# .vimrc is not being sourced properly

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I have following lines in my vimrc

```
colorscheme solarized
```

This obviously sets solarized colorscheme. My actual .vimrc is definitely longer than this and I also specify more options for solarized. However, the problem I am facing can be demonstrated using this minimum vimrc file.

When I open vim (version 7.3), it starts with a black background with solarized colorscheme. When I do `:source ~/.vimrc` to source the vimrc again it shifts to the light background. After that I can source vimrc multiple times and the background remains light.

Quite apart from the fact that this might be a bug in solarized, I fail to understand how the same vimrc can produce different behaviour when sourced in vim.

I am hopefully looking for pointers on how to go about debugging this.

UPDATE:

After the comment from @jim-stewart I did a bit more thorough debugging.
Added echo statements in my `.vimrc` and `solarized.vim`.

I found that when my `.vimrc` is run, `solarized.vim` is sourced and the correct
color palette (in my case `elseif g:solarized_termcolors !=
256 && &t_Co >= 16`) is set.

Then `.vimrc` reaches its end (executing other commands if any) and 
then `solarized.vim` is sourced again but
this time the color palette is set wrongly to (`if(has("gui_running") &&
(g:solarized_degrade == 0))`). I have checked variables in this `if` statement
and they have correct values and this color palette should not be set.

I don't know why `solarized.vim` is being sourced twice and that too
wrongly the second time. Once I am inside vim and invode
`:echo g:colors_name` then it generates `E121` error and tells me that the
variable is not being set.

Now, from inside `vim` if I invode `:colorscheme solarized` then I get 
correct solarized theme depending on the `background`. Also, `:echo
g:colors_name` returns `solarized`.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's toggling light/dark like that, but do you have `set background=dark` in your `.vimrc`?  Try putting that before the `colorscheme` line to always use dark.

Comment: Do you have a VimEnter autocommand set up somewhere that might be doing this?