# gvim solarized won't load all it's settings on first run

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I use solarized as my colorscheme with some customizations in my vimrc file. But strangely they get won't get applied when gVim starts. I need to source the config one time for the solarized settings to get taken over. Said options are:

> `let g:solarized_contrast = "low"`
>   `let g:solarized_visibility = "high"`
>   `let g:solarized_hitrail = 1`

A very similar question is [.vimrc is not being sourced properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774516/vimrc-is-not-being-sourced-properly) but no answer was found. I can't comment on the old topic (why?!)

.vimrc is hosted [here](https://github.com/tairun/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrc.win)

Comment: You need to have 50 rep to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) everywhere.

Comment: You need a reputation of 50 to be able to comment: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment . Nearly there!

Comment: Ok thanks. Wasn't aware of this limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `colorscheme solarized` ***after*** all of the `let g:solarized_` variables are set.

The solarized colorscheme script uses these flags to determine how it is going to set your colours as it is loaded.

Comment: Kinda makes sense... :-/. Thank you. I thought it would work the other way round, that I needed to overwrite the values called by the colorscheme. But looks like vim is able to pass them to the command.